# The Windows Installer XML variable 'WixUICostingPopupOptOut' is declared in more than one location. Please remove one of the declarations

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

I have created a setup for my web application using wix 3.7 but on building the WIX setup I got the following Error.

```
error LGHT0195: The Windows Installer XML variable 'WixUICostingPopupOptOut' is declared in more than one location.  Please remove one of the declarations.
```

I have searched a lot and got this solution.
I have added code below to my Product.wxs

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUICostingPopupOptOut" Overridable="yes" Value="1"/>
```

Not worked for me. Kindly help to fixing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did A quick search and found this link http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/10/09/experimental-results-part-ii/. "If you’ve built a customized dialog set, remove the WixUICostingPopupOptOut WiX variable definition from your dialog set fragment"

Comment: Thanks but it was issue of wix toolset version. Installed the latest version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while building an msi using 'WiX Toolset v3.11.2.4516' on Windows 10 and resolved it by adding `<WixVariable Id="WixUICostingPopupOptOut" Value="0" />` in 'Product.wxs' file.

As mentioned in the above answer, for more details please refer the link:
http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/10/09/experimental-results-part-ii/